# Blogger Layout - Anchor destroys layout

Tags: html, css, layout, blogger

I have a "funny'" problem with a blogger layout.

When I use the following URL, everything works fine:
[lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetu](http://tobikoskleinewelt.blogspot.de/2013/03/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consetetur.html)

But when I use this URL with the anchor (#comment-form), the layout is totally crazy:
[same as above with .html#comment-form](http://tobikoskleinewelt.blogspot.de/2013/03/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consetetur.html#comment-form)

It happens only on Chrome. Without any comments, nothing happens, but when comments are posted, some parts are pushed to the top somehow. I cant find the reason. ;(

Is it a JavaScript from blogger, which overwrites some stuff of mine? But why only in Chrome. Even IE is okay! ~~

hope someone has an idea. I'm a sad bear :(

Comment: both pages look the same to me (chrome for mac)

Comment: I see the differences, but I've no idea why it's doing it. By the way, I don't think you really need the empty `<a name="blah"></a>` any more, just setting an id on the appropriate element to go to and using that as your `#id` should be fine.

Comment: Where do you mean exactly?

Comment: Instead of `<div class='comment-form'><a name='comment-form'></a>` just use `<div class="comment-form" id="comment-form">`. (And if you have only one comment form on the page, an id is more appropriate anyway instead of a class.)

Comment: Understood what you mean. It's the way blogger made it, I have to change a lot for a "okay" css/html. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your CSS and noticed that if you remove `overflow:hidden` in `#content`, it fixes itself.

Comment: I used Tool > Developer Tools in Chrome. It is really useful tool when fixing CSS problems.